# Não estou conseguindo pegar o valor do textarea com java script

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

Boa noite pessoal, implementei um mural de avisos utilizando o textarea. O problema é que não estou conseguindo pegar esse valor que é digitado pelo usuário. Quando coloco esse valor dentro do Html ( VALOR QUALQUER) e dou um console.log ele me retorna o valor digitado, o problema é quando deixo ele em branco no html e espero esse valor do usuário.

## Mural de Avisos

```
        <button type="button" onclick="openModal1()" class="btn-modal1"> <i class="fa-solid fa-plus"></i></button>

        <div id="modal-container1" class="modal-container1">
            <div class="modal1">
                <button class="fechar1" id="fechar1">X</button>
                <h3>Novo post</h3>
                <input id="title" placeholder="Título">
                
                <textarea type="text" class="textarea" id="desc"></textarea> 

                <button onclick="newPost()">Salvar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Java Script:

```
function newPost () {

    let title = document.getElementById ('title').value
    let description = document.getElementById ('desc').value
    
    let post = {title, description}

    

    const options = {method: 'POST',
                     headers: new Headers ({'content-type': 'application/json'}), 
                     body: JSON.stringify(post)}

    fetch('http://192.168.1.110:5000/api/new', options).then(res => {
        console.log (res)

        updatePosts()

        document.getElementById ('title').value = ''
        document.getElementById ('desc').value = ''

    })

}
```

Comment: Retire os espaços depois de getElementById.

Comment: Gostaria que fosse simples assim kkk inclusive se realmente fosse isso eu ia jogar o pc fora!!! hahaha agradeço a atenção mas este não é o caso 
(a propósito, retirei os espaços rsrsr)

Comment: Fiz o teste com o código que forneceu e ele parece funcionar. Inclusive, ao dar um `console.log(options);` os valores são apresentados corretamente. Poderia ser mais específico quanto ao que precisa?

Comment: Dentro dessa tag <textarea type="text" class="textarea" id="desc">QUALQUER COISA</textarea> 
Se eu der um console.log(desc) eu consigo pegar esse valor "qualquer coisa", porém quando eu deixo ela vazia conforme imagem, e coloco texto lá no front eu não consigo resgatar esse valor o retorno é undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Pessoal vi que esse é um tema que já foi publicado em diversos forums, muitas pessoas com a mesma dúvida. Eu pesquisei a fundo e descobri como resolver meu problema:

```
function newPost () {

    let title = document.getElementById ('title').value
    let description = tinyMCE.get('myTextarea').getContent();
    

    let post = {title, description}

    const options = {method: 'POST',
                     headers: new Headers ({'content-type': 'application/json'}), 
                     body: JSON.stringify(post)}

    fetch('http://10.238.52.25:5000/api/new', options).then(res => {
        console.log (res)

        updatePosts()

        document.getElementById ('title').value = ''
        document.getElementById ('myTextarea').value = ''
    })

}
```

Essa variável é responsável por pegar o valor digitado pelo usuário:

let description = tinyMCE.get('myTextarea').getContent();

Comment: Link que me ajudou a entender: 
https://www.tiny.cloud/blog/how-to-get-content-and-set-content-in-tinymce/?gclid=EAIaIQobChMI58nf2PSH-gIVnRPUAR3VEgQIEAAYASAAEgJy6fD_BwE

Comment: Esqueceu de mencionar o tinyMCE na pergunta. Mas que bom que conseguiu solucionar.